# Unable to hide status bar on iOS 6,7 when presenting viewcontroller

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, statusbar

The following is my custom VC presentation code:

```
-(void)presentViewController:(UIViewController*)vc
{
    UIWindow *w = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window];
    UIViewController *parentController = (TabBarViewController *)[w rootViewController];

    [parentController addChildViewController:vc];
    if ([vc respondsToSelector:@selector(beginAppearanceTransition:animated:)]) // iOS 6
    {
        [vc beginAppearanceTransition:YES animated:YES];
    }
    UIView *toView = vc.view;
    [parentController.view addSubview:toView];
    toView.frame = parentController.view.bounds;

    CGAffineTransform tr = CGAffineTransformScale(self.view.transform, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    toView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(self.view.transform, 0.01f, 0.01f);;
    CGPoint oldCenter = toView.center;

    toView.center = ((RootViewControllerEx*)vc).cellCenter;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:4.5 animations:^{
            toView.transform = tr;
            toView.center = oldCenter;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        [vc didMoveToParentViewController:parentController];
        if ([vc respondsToSelector:@selector(endAppearanceTransition)]) // iOS 6
        {
            [vc endAppearanceTransition];
        }

    }];
}
```

It works fine, however, in presented VC I am hiding status bar:

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
    return YES;
}
```

When I present my VC using built-in `presentViewController:animated:completion:`, status bar in presented VC is hidden. But with my code on iOS 7 status bar is not hidden at all, on iOS 6 it is even more strange - status bar is hidden, but my view size is shorter from top by the size of status bar. So I can see a black gap from top on iOS 6. What should I do to properly hide status bar when using custom VC presentation?

Comment: Updated code to address issue with bounds. It addressed issue on iOS 6, but still can see iOS 7 status bar.

Comment: Also tried to set `modalPresentationStyle` to `UIModalPresentationFullScreen`. No good.

Answer (score 0):

you should try this in your viewDidLoad for differencing the IOS 6/7 status bar problem

```
 if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate)])
{
    //IOS 7 - Status Bar Hidden
    [self prefersStatusBarHidden];
    [self performSelector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate)];
    self.statusBarHidden = YES;
}
else
{
    // iOS 6 - Status Bar shown
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
    self.statusBarHidden = NO;
}
```

and an method for hiding status Bar

```
 - (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden{
return YES;}
```

and also add an property for status Bar

```
@property BOOL statusBarHidden;
```

then make sure that your view bounds to the screen size and fits correctly

I think this solves your problem :)

Answer (score -2):

Try this

in view did load

```
   [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarHidden = YES;
```

and set value in plist like

[image]

set this in project summary

[image]

and this in your interface builder

[image]

Comment: This only works on iOS6 and ONLY hides status bar. My new view controller is still showing gap in place of status bar. Please read my original question carefully.

Comment: check these property too

Comment: Again, status bar hides itself properly when using built in `presentViewController:animated:completion:` method in order to present it.